# Rearranging data columns in R

Tags: r, excel

I have an excel file that contains two columns : `Car_Model_Year` and `Cost`.

```
Car_Model_Year     Cost
2018              25000
2010              9000
2005              13000
2002              35000
1995              8000
```

I want to sort my data as follows:

```
Car_Model_Year     Cost
1995               8000
2002               35000
2005               13000
2010               9000
2018               25000
```

So now, the `Car_Model_Year` are sorted in ascending order. I wrote the following R code, but I don't know how to rearrange the values of the variable `Cost` accordingly.

```
my_data <- read.csv2("data.csv")
my_data <- sort(my_data$Car_Model_Year, decreasing = FALSE)
```

Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
sorted_df <- df[order(df$Car_Model_Year, df$Cost),]
print(sorted_df)
```

---

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2

  Car_Model_Year  Cost
           <dbl> <dbl>
1           1995  8000
2           2002 35000
3           2005 13000
4           2010  9000
5           2018 25000
```

Note that you can use signs (`+`/ `-`) to indicate `asc` or `desc`:

```
# Sort by car_model(descending) and cost(acending)
sorted_df <-df[order(-df$Car_Model_Year, df$Cost),]
```

Comment: Just one comment: if I have several 2018 rows with different values of Cost, how can I deal with that?

Comment: So the code will first sort on the car_model column, and then will sort on Cost column. So the 2018's will be repeated in rows, but it will be sorted from lowest cost that year to the highest cost that year. Try it, it will be easy to understand what's happening

Answer (score 1):

Does the below approach work? To sort by two or more columns, you just add them to the `order()` - i.e. order(var1, var2,...)

```
my_data <- data.frame(Car_Model_Year=c(2018,2010,2005,2002,1995),
                      Cost=c(25000,9000,13000,35000,8000))

sorted <- my_data[order(my_data$Car_Model_Year, my_data$Cost),]

> print(sorted)
  Car_Model_Year  Cost
5           1995  8000
4           2002 35000
3           2005 13000
2           2010  9000
1           2018 25000
```

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr::arrange()` makes it easy:

```
library(dplyr)
my_data %>% arrange(Car_Model_Year, Cost)
```

Descending price instead:

```
my_data %>% arrange(Car_Model_Year, desc(Cost))
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. This doesn't work for me.

Comment: You might need to install the library first, ```install.packages("dplyr")```, and then load it using ```library(dplyr)```